# Como surgir as imagens no local que o ponteiro do mouse se encontra?

Tags: vb.net, api, visual-basic-6

Preciso dar manutenção em um sistema que foi originalmente desenvolvido em [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6) e estou passando para [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net).

O sistema utiliza a api do inDesign CS2, cuja documentação é muito ruim.

Parte do programa consiste em arrastar algumas imagens de uma lista e colocá-las no arquivo inDesign aberto. Para isso estou usando o *place* e está funcionando. Mas eu preciso fazer com que as imagens apareçam exatamente no local que o ponteiro do mouse se encontra. E só estou conseguindo fazer aparecer em um ponto específico que eu passar.

Hoje está assim:

```
Dim myWindow = myDesign.ActiveWindow
Dim mySpread As InDesign.Spread = myWindow.activeSpread

Dim posFrame() As Integer = {0, 0}
Dim myImage As InDesign.PDF = mySpread.Place(nome, posFrame)
```

Ou seja, estou pegando a *spread* ativa, e nela colocando a imagem no ponto *0,0*. Preciso que apareça no local do mouse, independente de onde o mouse estiver.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que isso te ajuda (linha 250):

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/indesign/sdk/explodedSDK/cs.01/source/sdksamples/basicdragdrop/BscDNDCustomFlavorHelper.cpp;jsessionid=87E0DC71F1D0B53A5B11757E98CC68BF

Comment: Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia
o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter 
conteúdo aqui mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta;  
você poderia fazer isso?
Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! 
Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: 
[Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)

Comment: Valeu cara, só que assim, não manjo tanto de C++, mas me parece que na linha 250 ele está usando o objeto Util chamando o método GetStrokeBounds. Então quem realmente está pegando a posição é esse método, que não está detalhado nesse código. Ou seja, ainda não me ajudou, rs... Você tem o restante do código?